# 'downstairs' adverb vs noun

Tags: ambiguity

If you say "We need some manpower tomorrow to move some of the stuff downstairs." could you mean both "moving stuff down the stairs" and "move stuff that is downstairs"? Which is the more common understanding of it?

Comment: It can mean both, in my opinion.

Comment: I believe it is an example of _syntactic ambiguity_. I'm no expert on this.

Comment: It can mean both, but it is not a noun either way.

Comment: True, what is it then?

Comment: "Downstairs" is best analysed as a preposition: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/downstairs).

Comment: What @BillJ said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be understood either way. I don't know which is more common.

As the comments mention, "downstairs" acts as a prepositional phrase (so as a single word, it can be categorized as a "preposition"; you can see that it was originally formed by combining the preposition "down" with the noun "stairs").

Prepositional phrase attachment is a very common type of ambiguity in English (see this Language Log post by Mark Liberman: [Annals of parsing](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=27691)).